# How to use VoiceInteractionService with new changes in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, speech-recognition, voice-interaction

I want to implement hot key wording like "Hey Google" or "Hi Siri" to start the SpeechRecognizer in android.

I came across something called `VoiceInteractionService` to do that, but this seems changed a lot over the period of time and lot of methods and classes are turned to `@SystemApi`.
I cannot find any tutorial and article to how to use this now.
Can anyone help me out on how to use this or is there anything I can try to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.